# How to change the background color of segments of a segmented control

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I give different background colors to segments in a segmented control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out UISegmentedControl's [`tintcolor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/tintColor) property (Apple documentation is linked for you).

This only works is the style of the segmented control is `UISegmentedControlStyleBar`, though.

Otherwise, you might be able to fake it by putting in colored background images via the [`- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3abarMetrics%3a) method, but I've never tried this and don't know if this would do what you want.

Comment: The style of my control is plain

Comment: I kind of figured your style wouldn't be bar style (since you were asking the question).  Check out my edited answer (which talks about colored background images). This is a new API functionality available as of iOS 5. I hope this info helps!